# ChartJS - mark multiple regions on chart

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom, chartjs-plugin-annotation

Please advise,

i have ChartJS graph (4.4.1) which has X of 'time' type. I need somehow to select 3 periods on X axe.

I'm thinking of some trigger (checkbox) for activating each period selecting, so when that trigger for period is TRUE i can create rectangular annotation (somehow like Zoom plugin does, before actual zooming).

Additional functionalities needed:

- rescale period (y boundaries) with snapping to x labels
- drag annotation period with snapping to x labels
- removing period annotation / selection

Anyone had similar case?

So far I managed to create annotations from date pickers, but i'm far from needed behavior.

tnx in advance!
Y